# Websphere 7.0 - Why are the web server plug-in properties not editable

Tags: websphere

Websphere 7.0 - Why are the web server plug-in properties not editable?

The values are grayed out and not editable under Application servers > server1 > Web server plug-in properties

Answer (score 0):

After further review, it appears this is because of the 'user' that is logging into the console does not have the proper authority.